# 英語が残っている：ゲストとして投稿

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

電子メールのテックスボックスの中に英語が残っている。

> required, but 表示しない

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup　のメールアドレスの説明と揃えたほうがいいのでは？

Comment: あ、そうか、気づいてなかった。それも良いかもしれません。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[登録ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)から、

> 必須ですが、公開はされません

Comment: 「表示されません」だとバグっぽくも聞こえるので、hinaloeさん案をミックスして「公開はされません」にしてみました。

Comment: [unaristさんがTransifexで適用しました](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289976?q=required%2C%20but)。

Answer (score 3):

> 必要ですが表示はされません

あるいは

> 公開されませんが必要です